# multipart POST request directly in ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: cocoa, post, asiformdatarequest

So you think it would be easy to find a direct example of POST information to ASIFormDataRequest, but I havent found a 1:1 in these formats.  Here's the POST request I want to send:

```
POST /fileXfer HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
Content-Length: 200
AppID:myID
TransferID:abcd1234

-- AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="xxx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 100

... contents of file ...

--AaB03x--
```

EDIT:

Turns out my problems were more with the server receiving the data.  But this is what I ended up with!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://IP:PORT/fileXfer"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];

//Sets headers of POST
[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Application-Id" value:@"myID"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Transfer-Id" value:@"abcd1234"];

//Sets data
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:kEncryptedFilePath];
[request setData:fileData withFileName:@"xxx" andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"data"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

I also added the following line to ASIFormDataRequest's buildMultipartFormDataPostBody where Content-Disposition and Content-Type are set:

```
[self appendPostString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length: %lu\r\n\r\n", [data length]]];`
```

I'm not sure if there's an easier way to add that line directly from the request, but out of the things I tried, this seemed to be the one that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building the HTTP body manually, which may lead to errors, you should better use the methods provided by `ASIFormDataRequest`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://IP:PORT/fileXfer"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Application-Id" value:@"myID"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Transfer-Id" value:@"abcd1234"];

[request setData:[self fileData] withFileName:@"xxx" andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"data"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What you said makes sense for leaving out the Content-Length and Content-Type because those are filled in by ASIFormDataRequest.  However, I cannot check the contents of the body, and this seems to be where my error is still occurring.  Is there a way to check this content? I've tried using setData, addData, setFile, and addFile in place of the `setData` line above.

Comment: You can send `buildPostBody` to the request, then read the `postBody` property.

Comment: I still seem to be getting (null) for the postBody when I do that.  However, if I print `fileData` at the end of `addData` (which is called by `setData`), the contents include the contentType, my data, the file name and key.

Comment: In that case, you can get the HTTP body by reading the contents of the file a `postBodyFilePath`.

Comment: Thanks, that let me see my data.  I'm still getting timeout/connection errors, though.  I can't tell if its the remote server or my code though...